# SQL Server database - how to query?

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to make such thing: for each country determine the year in which the maximum number of ships was launched. In case when for one country it will be more than one year - choose smaller.

Could someone help me please?

This is the database:

[image]

[image]

Output must be following : country, amount of ships, year

```
Japan       | 1 | 1913
USA         | 3 | 1941
Gt Britain  | 6 | 1916
```

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you posted data and ddl instead of pictures. The basic gist of one way to solve this is to use ROW_NUMBER partitioned by Country and Year descending. Then get those with the ROW_NUMBER value of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select country, launched, cnt
from
(
    select country, launched, cnt, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by country order by cnt desc, launched asc) as rn
    from
    (
        select c.country, s.launched, count(*) as cnt 
        from @classes c
        inner join @ships s on c.class = s.class
        group by c.country, s.launched
    )sq1
)sq2 where rn = 1
```

Comment: amount of ships is not correct in the output, output of your code:           Japan       | 1 | 1913
USA         | 1 | 1941
Gt Britain  | 1 | 1916 ,                                                                                                              Amount of ships in all rows is - 1, but must be 1,3,6                                         Can you fix it?

Comment: my bad - fixed the select columns

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT
     C.Country,
     S.Launched,
     ShipCnt = COUNT(1)
     SeqNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY S.Launched ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC)
    FROM Classes C 
       INNER JOIN Ships S
           ON C.Class = S.Class
    GROUP BY C.Country,S.Launched
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE SeqNo = 1
```